# Nginx cache unmanaged growth

Tags: nginx, cache

We have two Nginx servers with independent local caches for caching images. Periodically there is problem with unmanaged growth of cache's size. This size may be far larger than `max_size` in `nginx.conf`. As a result cache occupies all free disk space.

I want to understand what the reason of this issue might be.

Proxy cache config (`nginx.conf`):

```
proxy_cache_path /opt2/nginx-cache-images1 max_size=150g levels=2:2 keys_zone=images1:1024m inactive=24h;
proxy_temp_path /opt2/proxy_temp 1 2;
```

Size of `/opt2/nginx-cache-images1` is ~200GB.

Config of site location:

```
location / {
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Is-Referer-Search-Engine $is_referer_search_engine;
   proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
   proxy_hide_header Content-Disposition;
   proxy_pass http://ua-image-proxy;
   default_type image/jpeg;

   proxy_cache images1;
   proxy_cache_key ua$request_uri$is_referer_search_engine;
   proxy_cache_valid 200 24h;
   proxy_cache_valid 301 24h;
   proxy_cache_valid 404 1h;
}
```

Nginx version: 1.7.7 and 1.7.9.
It was compiled on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What is output of `du -kcd1 /opt2/nginx-cache-images1` ?

Comment: After restarting nginx service all things goes ok. But periodically this issue happens. Full output of du - [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XFLLjVmrthgxts_BKndBs5y4-YVv8fhoXD7YR_7clVs/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Also when the issue will happen I'll post another result of du command.

Comment: Now I have the same problem. Cache size is bigger than max_size. Result of du command you can see on the following link: [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1INni3IA8JEsGqT5v_xXTcoUVILun995NPfADIoYxakY/edit?usp=sharinghttps://docs.google.com/document/d/1INni3IA8JEsGqT5v_xXTcoUVILun995NPfADIoYxakY/edit?usp=sharing). Is it useful?

Comment: We have this on one of our busiest caches. It's like the cache manager just stops deleting anything for a period of time. Sometimes it recovers after a while and starts deleting a lot of files, only to start rising again. Often these situations seem to coincide with a burst of traffic. Judging by reports elsewhere this has been a problem since at least nginx 1.6.1.

Answer (score 2):

For me this was fixed in nginx [1.13.1](http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES):

> Workaround: now cache manager ignores long locked cache entries when
>          cleaning cache based on the "max_size" parameter.